# How to Create Slide Up From Bottom Menu With Overlay Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, menu

I'm building an iPhone app in Swift. I would like my users to have a menu slide up from the bottom when they tap a button on the table view. Instagram has a very good example of what I am trying to do:

[image]

You see how when the user taps the button, the menu slides up from the bottom, and the rest of the table view has a black overlay with a low alpha (it's see through)? This is what I would like to implement, but I have no idea how to do it. Do I add two views to my table view, one for the overlay, and one for the menu, and animate them to appear on the button tap? How would I get the views to "Float" above the table view? Or, do I need to add another View Controller and have it partially transition with some sort of custom segue? I'm fairly new to programming so I'm not sure how to go about this. What do I do?

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean just a UIAlertController? If so, refer to https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/

Here's a tutorial on using a UIAlertController:
http://nshipster.com/uialertcontroller/

Comment: Yes this is just a native `UIKit` object that can be overridden and modified to make it look how you want.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to do. I did not realize it was that simple. Thanks.

Comment: @Josh Great, glad I could help you!